# How to extract Lindemann Index from LAMMPS dump files?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, ovito

I used a python code to extract [Lindemann index](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Physics:Lindemann_index) from dump files. But the problem is the code works fine with dump files with little amount of data and atoms. When I use large files if shows overflow for python data types. Is there any alternative way to extract Lindemann Index ?

Comment: Please add your code and the errors you encounter in the question.
Also example dump files.

Comment: Do you refer to this entry on PyPI [lindemann](https://pypi.org/project/lindemann/)?